# sql min date returning more than 1 record

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to return 1 record per customer, along with the first record from another table (product). The tables are joined with an intersection table, and the date that I am using the min (date) on is a user input date.

My sql would work fine except i have noticed there a few customer which have more than one record in the product table with the same date, so they are being returned more than once.  I want to just be able to return 1 product per customer. Database is oracle so I have tried using rownum but then only returning 1 record for the whole query so i'm obviously not using it correctly.  This is my sql

```
SELECT  cust.ROW_ID prod.NAME, prod.DATE
FROM cust INNER JOIN ProdCust on cust.ROW_ID = ProdCust.CUST_ID
          INNER JOIN prod on ProdCust .PROD_ID = Prod.ROW_ID
          INNER JOIN
                    (SELECT ProdCust.CUST_ID, MIN (Prod.DATE) minDate
                     FROM ProdCust, Prod
                     WHERE ProdCust.PROD_ID = Prod.ROW_ID
                     GROUP BY CUST_ID
                    ) ProdCustMin on ProdCust.CUST_ID = ProdCustMin.CUST_ID AND prod.DATE = ProdCustMin.minDate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use `row_number()` to resolve ties:

```
SELECT  c.ROW_ID
,       p.NAME
,       p.DATE
FROM    Cust c
JOIN    (
        SELECT  row_number() over (partition by pc.CUST_ID order by p.DATE) rn
        ,       pc.CUST_ID
        ,       p.NAME
        ,       p.DATE
        FROM    Prod p
        JOIN    ProdCust pc 
        ON      pc.PROD_ID = p.ROW_ID
        ) p
ON      c.ROW_ID = p.CUST_ID
        AND p.rn = 1 -- First row only
```